# How to write from an input port to a file in racket without storing string/bytestring in memory?

Tags: port, racket

I'm looking for a way to stream the content of an input port to a file in racket without holding the string/bytestring in memory but instead stream the content from port to port and I can't seem to find the way to do it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may want `copy-port`.

Comment: yes indeed, thank you so much Ryan